# Using Nant to build and deploy asp.net, vb.net , framework 1.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, build, nant

How can I use properly Nant to build and deploy an asp.net project developed using asp.net , vb.net and .net framework 1.1?

I tried with this build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="MyWebProj" default="build" basedir=".">
    <description>...</description>
    <property name="debug" value="true" overwrite="false"
    />
    <property name="basename" value="MyWebProj" />
    <target name="build">
        <mkdir dir="NantBIN" />
        <vbc target="library" output="NantBIN/${basename}.dll" debug="${debug}">
            <sources>
                <include name="*.vb" />
            </sources>
        </vbc>
    </target>
</project>
```

And I run this bat file:

```
@echo off bin\nant -t:net-1.1 -buildfile:.MyWebProjPath pause
```

Comment: **I tried with this build file:** ``<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MyWebProj" default="build" basedir=".">
 <description>...</description>
 <property name="debug" value="true" overwrite="false" />
 <property name="basename" value="MyWebProj"/>
 <target name="build">
  <mkdir dir="NantBIN" />
        <vbc target="library" output="NantBIN/${basename}.dll" debug="${debug}">
            <sources>
    <include name="*.vb"/>
   </sources>
        </vbc>
    </target>
</project> `` .   **And I run this bat file:** ``@echo off
bin\nant -t:net-1.1 -buildfile:.MyWebProjPath
pause``

Comment: @gardenunez Welcome to SO. You should edit your questions to include follow up information in future, so it is easier for people to locate relevant information, particularly data that merits being structured such as XML. I have added this for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for your help and recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you for all the answers and advices.
This is how I finally resolved the problem.I use this as the build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><project name="..." default="rebuild" basedir=".">
<target name="rebuild" depends="build">
    <call target="build.copy"/>
</target>
<target name="build" description="Build all targets.">
    <call target="build.project"/>
</target>
<target name="build.project">
    <solution configuration="${configuration}" solutionfile="${solutionName}" outputdir="${expected.output}">
        <webmap>
            <map url="${webproj.url}" path="${webproj.name}" />
        </webmap>
    </solution>
</target>
<target name="build.copy">
    <copy  todir="${path.to.deploy}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset basedir=".">
            ...
            <include name="**\*.asp" />
            <include name="**\*.aspx" />
            <include name="**\*.css" />
            <include name="**\*.js" />
            ...
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

And I run this bat file (is important to set -t:net-1.1 to specify the .net framework version ):

```
bin\nant -t:net-1.1 -buildfile:.MyWebProjPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below links which explain step by step process for you.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123713/Automate-Publishing-a-WebSite-into-IIS-using-MSDep

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150759/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120104-1.aspx

Comment: In this articles they used the MSBuild command mostly. I guess I cannot use that on .net framework 1.1 or there is a way to use it?